# VisualforceAccessMetrics: Persmissions to Access this Salesforce Object

Tags: visualforce, permissions, classic

I am running this query in Classic =>

```
SELECT ApexPageId, ApexPage.Name, DailyPageViewCount, Id, Profile.Name, MetricsDate, LogDate 
   FROM VisualforceAccessMetrics ORDER BY ProfileId
```

But, I am getting this error => 
    `Error: sObject type 'VisualforceAccessMetrics' is not supported`

I believe that It is something related to System Permissions of the Profile. I have been searched but I didnt find what is the permission that is missing. I believe that is something related with the metadata.

Best Regards
Orlando

Comment: i think you will need api enabled on profile level.

Comment: @sanketkumar I have APi Enabled but the query is still not working.

Comment: @oagostinho  Are you trying this SOQL from the developer console?

Comment: this object became available in Summer 17; are you executing this in code that is at a version prior to summer17?

Answer (score 0):

It is an access issues. Make sure you have proper rights to access and query this object. I faced the same issue with non-admin user.